# customization in protobuf java generated code

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc-java, proto

We have a use case where, we have many RPC defined in different-different .proto files , and we generate a java based grpc stub code by using google's protobuf-java & protoc-gen-grpc-java as gradle plugin.
The requirement is we want to generate a new Service which flips the request, response and add stream to new flipped rpc.
So for example :

```
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

to be converted to like

```
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  rpc SayHelloStreaming (stream HelloReply) returns (stream HelloRequest) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

In java generated code I should be having 2 services for each original service. We just want the final java generated code to be having 2 services, the parser may/may not update original .proto files.

Is this customization possible with current protoc ? Can we extend the plugin and write ours -> Can someone please give some pointers.

Comment: Instead of trying to modify/extend protoc and the Java plugin why not add your own pre-processing step that generates your 2nd proto file from the first proto file? This pre-processor will just insert SayHelloStreaming rpc in the service.

Comment: Yes that would work as well.. but writing a failsafe parser which parses all rpc and run in production might be tricky. If you know the Google protobuf class which does the same, please point the same.. I can have a look at that to write our own such

Comment: Sorry I don't know the protoc structure but it has plugins so you might be able to add a plugin (which emits this additional streaming rpc). That is better than messing with protoc or the Java plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear to me.

Revising proto files is a fundamental requirement of gRPC.

The Java [tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/quickstart/#update-the-grpc-service) on https://grpc.io includes an example of adding a method to a service. In part, this is because adding|removing|updating methods|messages|fields is a common behavior.

> **NOTE** To clarify nomenclature, in your example, you're proposing adding a method to an existing service (definition). If you consider the proto as defining an API, this represents a non-breaking change. See [Versioning gRPC services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/versioning) for a good overview. Existing clients will continue to work (they are only aware of `SayHello`) while new clients will be aware of `SayHelloStreaming` too.